# Json encoding mcrypt_create_iv salt error

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to encode an array into JSON format, the array contains a hashed password and a salt, but the array does not get encoded for some reason and I believe it has to do with the characters in the salt, is there anyway around this or am I unable to JSON encode something that contains such characters?

```
$options = [ 
            'cost' => 12,
            'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
           ];

$salt = $options['salt'];
$arr = array('password' => 1, 'salt' => $salt);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your binary string has (unintended) invalid UTF-8 inside; to make it valid, you can encode the string using [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/utf8_encode):

```
$arr = array('password' => 1, 'salt' => utf8_encode($salt));
```

Later you will have to perform the operation in reverse:

```
$options = json_decode('...', true);
$salt = utf8_decode($options['salt']);
```

If you don't feel comfortable with such binary treatment, you could also perform a textual encoding like [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64_encode) which you can later decode using `base64_decode()`:

```
$arr = array('password' => 1, 'salt' => base64_encode($salt));
```